# Miranda book Proposition 3.10 pag. 40

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $F$ and $G$ be two holomorphic maps between Riemann surfaces $X$ and $Y$. If $F=G$ on a subset $S$ of $X$ with a limit point in $X$, then $F=G$.

Choose two charts $(U_\alpha,\phi_\alpha)$ and $(V_\alpha,h_\alpha)$ such that $x \in U_\alpha$ and $F(x)=G(x) \in V_\alpha$. We know that $f_\alpha=h_\alpha F \phi_\alpha ^{-1}$ and $g_\alpha=h_\alpha G \phi_\alpha ^{-1}$ are holomorphic, so the set $S_\alpha=\{z \in \phi_\alpha(U_\alpha):f_\alpha(z)=g_\alpha(z)\}$ is discrete in $\phi_\alpha (U_\alpha)$ cause it is the zero set of a holomorphic function. Now we see that $S \cap U_\alpha = \phi_\alpha ^{-1} (S_\alpha)$, so $S \cap U_\alpha$ is discrete in $X$.
How I should continue?

Comment: I think you've made an assumption for the sake of contradiction? If $F=G$ everywhere, then $S_a$ is not discrete, so it seems you've assumed they are not equal on all of $X$. Now choose the $U_0$ that contains the limit point. $S_0$ will have a limit point which contradicts the discreteness.

Comment: You need to assume that the domain X is connected.